# Fill character buffer piece by piece

Tags: fortran

I am trying, in Fortran 2008, to fill a large character buffer piece by piece, in an efficient and readable way.

For background, the code is for the output routine of a molecular dynamics code. It should create the contents for an output file containing atom properties. The exact format for each property depends on its value. The contents are buffered and written in a single call using MPI-IO, so just writing directly to the file is not an option. The buffer can be assumed to be large enough.

In C, this would be simple to achieve with `sprintf`, which returns the number of bytes written. That can then be used to calculate where the next piece should be written.

In Fortran, I am not aware of a way to get the number of characters written by the `write` statement. This means that I must use ugly and brittle code, such as:

```
integer :: nchars, len, iatom
character(len=SOMETHING_LARGE) :: strbuf

nchars = 0

! In a loop of iatom = 1, numatoms
! Many similar writes, with different cases for the format
! based on the actual values.
len = 3 * (1 + 11)
write(strbuf(nchars+1 : nchars+len), &
      '(3(1x,f11.7))') x(:, iatom)
nchars = nchars + len
```

Note that I must manually calculate the length of the piece written to the buffer, since not passing an upper bound means that the rest of the (200MB) buffer is padded with spaces. This means that I cannot use formats that automatically determine the number of digits to use. Also, the code breaks if the format is changed without changing `len`. Also, I consider it ugly that `len` has to be passed as the end point of the string slice.

I have devised a workaround by wrapping the C `sprintf` using `bind(C)`. What makes this very ugly is that, since vararg functions are explicitly excluded from `bind(C)` by the Fortran standard, I must first write a non-vararg wrapper in C separately for each parameter type combination (e.g. 'string,real,real,int,real', 'string,string,real,real,real,int', ...), and then write a `bind(C)` interface to each of those in Fortran. While this is slightly less brittle (and 50% faster for some reason), it is still ugly, especially since it mixes C and Fortran.

For comparison, the same code in pure C:

```
char *buf = ...;
char *ptr = buf;
...
ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%g %g %g", x[3*i], x[3*i+1], x[3*i+2]);
```

Is there a way to achieve similar clarity and robustness in Fortran?

Comment: Clarity lies in the eye of the beholder. Especially when it comes to pure C and pointers.

Comment: Quite how does len vary with the things to be written? Why are you converting to a string anyway? There are good reasons but they are rare, so there may be a better way to achieve what you are really trying to do. And why does the buffer need to be so big?

Comment: @IanBush With large values,  the number of digits printed is increased. Normally, I would just use a format that uses a sufficient amount of digits, but that wastes a lot of space for typical strings. The string is eventually written to a file, and the user the analyses the file using other programs. Each MPI rank converts its own data to a string, then they all call `MPI_File_write_all`, passing their buffers. The buffer is sized large enough that only very few MPI calls are required.

Comment: OK, thought as much. Firstly, having done this myself, in retrospect I would recommend using netcdf or HDF5 instead. Secondly why not just make it an array of character variables, with each member being the right length for a single "record"? Thirdly I appreciate why you want it big, but 200MByte does seem rather excessive - have you benchmarked the solution as a function of buffer size?

Comment: I cannot change the output format, since users depend on it staying the same, for interoperability with both custom scripts and programs like OVITO. The size of a record is not fixed, i.e. some lines can be longer than others. This is actually one reason I am looking for a solution, since I want to be able to remove all unnecessary spaces using formats like I0 or G0. That is currently not possible, since I must know the length written to know where to write next.

Comment: I have not done benchmarks as a function of buffer size. In a good solution, the buffer size should not matter for speed when filling the buffer, and for MPI, I would imagine it is best to pass the full buffer once, instead of many smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the compiler/process keep track of the length

```
character(len=37) strtmp
character(len=:), allocatable :: strbuf
strbuf = ''
!
! In your loop...
!
   write(strmp, '(3(1X,F11.7))') x(:,iatom)
   strbuf = trim(strbuf) // strtmp
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but doesn't this reallocate the whole string with each write? Since there can be tens of thousands of writes to fill the buffer, wouldn't this be quite slow?

Comment: Yes, it re-allocates.  You can use your static buffer in the same manner.  Replace the declaration with `character(len=SOME_LARGE_NUMBER) strbuf`.  The key here is that you don't need to keep track of len.  Fortran isn't C.

Comment: For a very large buffer I'd worry much more about the Trim of strbuf than the realloation - you've potentially (depending on the implementation) turned an O(N) solution into an O(N**2) one

Comment: @IanBush Yes, I checked that. Using this solution with trim and concatenation changes the runtime for my test case from 2s to long enough that I did not wait for it to finish.

Comment: @IanBush, never claimed it would be efficient for any sized buffer.  Personally, I would not convert `x(:,iatom)` into a string and then save the string.  It would be better to use `ACCESS="stream"` on opening the file and writing the floating point value directly.  That is 4 bytes for a `REAL` and 8 bytes for `DOUBLE PRECISION`.

Comment: Problem is the guy wants to do parallel I/O, for which MPI-I/O is the only game in town, and further due to constraints placed on him by his/her users he/she wants it to look like a Fortran formatted file, so he has to do his own conversions - Access="stream" doesn't address the needs of the question, unfortunately.